# Javascript library to parse PHP date formats

Tags: javascript, php, date

Just as the title states, is there a small javascript library that will allow me to output a date object according to PHP date formatting rules?

Example: `console.log(dateobj.toString("F j, Y"));`

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com).

Comment: @tadman—what search terms should the OP use to find a javascript library for formatting dates using PHP tokens? I was able to find [*these*](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=javascript%20PHP%20date%20format), but you might have better luck.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, i got him wrong at first time :) please see updated reply, @RobG

Comment: You say "parse" and "output" in the question. "Parse" means "turn from string into date" and "output" means "turn from date into string". Which direction are you concerned with?

Answer (score -3):

** Updated

Sorry for the last reply, it wasn't so proper, you can use this library that gives you nearly the same functionality and formatting just like PHP date_format.

[Download Here](https://github.com/jacwright/date.format)

You can start using like:

```
var myDate = new Date();
alert(myDate.format('d-m-Y')); // Outputs "26-11-2017"
alert(myDate.format('d-m-Y H:i:s')); // Outputs "26-11-2017 15:24:30"
alert(myDate.format('M jS, Y')); // Outputs "Nov 26th, 2017"
alert(myDate.format('\\T\\o\\d\\a\\y \\i\\s d-m-Y')); // Outputs "Today is 26-11-2017"
```

**Note: Escaping letters can be done by typing \ in front of a letter.

Comment: Not clear that moment.js accepts PHP date format parameters. Does it?

Comment: [Moment.js tokens](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) are different to [PHP tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), . The question is off–topic. BTW, how did you determine that moment.js is the most popular library for formatting using PHP tokens?